# repeat traceroute for each ips based on count=2

Tags: python

```
import subprocess
import re

def calculate_average_hop_count(ip_address, count):
    try:
        hop_counts = []
        
        for _ in range(count):
            print(f'Trace for IP: {ip_address}')
            command = f"tracert {ip_address}"
            process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
            output, error = process.communicate()

            if output:
                output = output.decode()
                print(output)
            else:
                print("No output received.")
                continue

            lines = output.splitlines()

            for line in lines:
                if line.startswith("  "):
                    hop_count = line.split()[0]
                    try:
                        hop_counts.append(int(hop_count))
                    except ValueError:
                        pass

        if "Destination net unreachable" in output:
            return None

        if not hop_counts:
            return None

        average_hop_count = sum(hop_counts) / len(hop_counts)
        print("Average hop count:", average_hop_count)
        return average_hop_count

    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Error executing traceroute command: {e}")
        return None

input_file = "C:\\Users\\ALFA\\Downloads\\Desktop\\New folder\\aaa.txt"
with open(input_file, "r") as file:
    ip_addresses = file.read().splitlines()

count = 3  # Number of times to repeat traceroute for each IP address

averages = []

for ip in ip_addresses:
    average = calculate_average_hop_count(ip, count)
    if average is not None:
        print("Average hop count:", average)
        averages.append((ip, average))
    else:
        averages.append((ip,))

output_file = "C:\\Users\\ALFA\\Downloads\\Desktop\\New folder\\ip_average1.txt"
with open(output_file, 'w') as file:
    for element in averages:
        if len(element) == 2:
            ip, average = element
            file.write(f"{average}\n")
        else:
            ip = element[0]
            file.write(f"\n")

print(f"Average hop counts for IP addresses that reach the destination saved to '{output_file}'.")
```

why ip not repeat based on count?

Comment: can you pls format your code better as well as give more info?

Comment: this code not repeat traceroute for each IP based on count=2.please,give solution for this problem?

Comment: I tried your code and it repeats for me.